# Liferay Search Container Sorting Without executing doview method

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, searchcontainer

I have created a MVC portlet in liferay 6.2. In that portlet i am using search container with sorting.
Whenever I click on column of search container it works perfectly fine but it executes Do View method every time. Is it possible to execute another action when click on the column label.
DoView method is getting Complete list of Users but I want some particular list of users to be sort.

Comment: How is your `search container` getting the values in the beginning when it is loaded? Is it displaying all the users or just some particular list of users?

Comment: When first time portlet is loaded,It is getting a list of users from DoView Method and displaying in View.jsp . After that using search action I am filtering the user's list.

Comment: Please provide some sample code.